# JProfiler: The IDE could not locate the selected class

Tags: jprofiler

JProfiler 7.1.2 integrated with Eclipse 3.6.2

When I right click on  a class/method name and select "Show Source"，JProfiler just alerts me "The IDE could not locate the selected class"

is it an issue of JProfiler? How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this an inner class or an anonymous class?

Comment: Actually it shows the same alert for any class.

Comment: Then the JProfiler plugin cannot accurately resolve the source path of your project. Is there anything special about where the sources for the selected classes reside? Can you try with another project?

Comment: It seems the problem only occurs when profiling webapps.

Comment: I tried reinstalling eclipse,setting up new workspace,creating new web project and the problem remains.
Sources can be shown in eclipse when profiling simple java application.